# При отправке письма через сайт, почта майл ру показывает иероглифы. Как это исправить? А гугл отправляет в спам. Как решить данный вопрос?

Tags: phpmailer

```
<?
// пример использования
$file = "site/po.pdf"; // файл
 $semail=$_POST['email']; // кому

$from = "admin@xn--h1aaebcjfeabed4bze.xn--p1ai"; // от кого
$subject = "Здравствуйте!"; // тема письма




$message = ' 
<html lang="ru"> 
    <head> 



        <title>Здравствуйте</title> 

    <style>
   hr {
    border: none; /* Убираем границу */
    background-color: Orange; /* Цвет линии */
    color: Orange; /* Цвет линии для IE6-7 */
    height: 2px; /* Толщина линии */
   }
  </style>

  <style>
   h1 {
    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif; /* Гарнитура текста */ 
    font-size: 250%; /* Размер шрифта в процентах */ 
   } 
   p {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 17pt; /* Размер шрифта в пунктах */ 
   }
  </style>

    </head> 

    <body>

    <a class="header__logo"><img src="http://по.рф/site/img/logo.png"  alt="Logo"></a>



<hr>



        <img src="http://по.рф/site/img/advantages-img.png" alt="Письма мастера дзен" align="left" > 



<h1>Здравствуйте!</h1>

   <p>     Я-Сергей 
</p> 


<hr>

    </body> 
</html>'; 


$r = sendMailAttachment($semail, $from, $subject, $message, $file); // отправка письма c вложением
echo ($r)?'Письмо отправлено':'Ошибка. Письмо не отправлено!';
//$r = sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message); // отправка письма без вложения
//echo ($r)?'Письмо отправлено':'Ошибка. Письмо не отправлено!';


/**
* Отправка письма с вложением

* @param string $from
* @param string $subject
* @param string $message
* @param string|bool $file - не обязательный параметр, путь до файла
* 
* @return bool - результат отправки
*/

function sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message, $file = false){
    $separator = "---"; // разделитель в письме
    // Заголовки для письма
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n"; // задаем от кого письмо
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$separator\""; // в заголовке указываем разделитель
    // если письмо с вложением
    if($file){
        $bodyMail = "--$separator\n"; // начало тела письма, выводим разделитель
        $bodyMail .= "Content-type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n"; // кодировка письма
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable"; // задаем конвертацию письма
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n"; // задаем название файла
        $bodyMail .= $message."\n"; // добавляем текст письма
        $bodyMail .= "--$separator\n";
        $fileRead = fopen($file, "r"); // открываем файл
        $contentFile = fread($fileRead, filesize($file)); // считываем его до конца
        fclose($fileRead); // закрываем файл
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n"; 
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; // кодировка файла
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n";
        $bodyMail .= chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFile))."\n"; // кодируем и прикрепляем файл
        $bodyMail .= "--".$separator ."--\n";
    // письмо без вложения
    }else{
        $bodyMail = $message;
    }
    $result = mail($mailTo, $subject, $bodyMail, $headers); // отправка письма
    return $result;
}
     header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);


?>
```